# Автоматическое отображение видео на youtube в ускоренном режиме

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chrome-extension, youtube, youtube-api

Подскажите скрипт либо расширение для Google Chrome для автоматического ускоренного воспроизведения видео на youtube.
Я хочу, что б все видео на ютубе отображались с удвоенной скоростью.
Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл расширение Google Chrome **Video Speed Controller**